# regular expression to exclude filetypes from find

Tags: regex, linux, unix, find

When using `find` command in linux, one can add a `-regex` flag that uses emacs regualr expressions to match.

I want find to look for all files except `.jar` files and `.ear` files. what would be the regular expression in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need a regex here. You can use `find` with the `-name` and `-not` options:

```
find . -not -name "*.jar" -not -name "*.ear"
```

A more concise (but less readable) version of the above is:

```
find . ! \( -name "*.jar" -o -name "*.ear" \)
```

Comment: I agree, regex would probably be overkill.

Comment: you are right, but i am trying to make it as generic as possible since i am using it as a function and don't know what will be the end user's needs

Comment: Excluding most of the files except some seems possible with a compound condition ```'(' -not -regex 'MOST_EXCLUDE' -or -regex 'SOME_INCLUDE' ')'```.

Comment: Does -o prefix stand for "or" to combine both file types? Can it be used in any other bash command?

Answer (score 15):

EDIT: New approach:

Since POSIX regexes don't support lookaround, you need to negate the match result:

```
find . -not -regex ".*\.[je]ar"
```

The previously posted answer uses lookbehind and thus won't work here, but here it is for completeness' sake:

```
.*(?<!\.[je]ar)$
```

Comment: can't seem to make it work in the command. i am using `find . -type 'f' -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*(?<!\.[je]ar)$'` and it gives me ` warning: you have specified the -regextype option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-regextype affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
`

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to place the `regextype` option after the `regex` option. But `posix-extended` doesn't sound right; POSIX doesn't have lookaround AFAIK.

Comment: Oops. It looks like `find` only supports POSIX BRE/ERE engines. In that case, this solution isn't going to work at all. Sorry about that (who upvoted this??)...

Comment: it says that valid types are `findutils-default', `awk', `egrep', `emacs', `gnu-awk', `grep', `posix-awk', `posix-basic', `posix-egrep', `posix-extended'.

Answer (score 10):

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -not -regex ".*\\.(jar|ear)"
```

This will do the job, and I personally find it a bit clearer than some of the other solutions. Unfortunately the -regextype is required (cluttering up an otherwise simple command) to make the capturing group work.

Comment: I agree that regex is not overkill, and is quickly scalable too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression in this case sounds like an overkill (you could just check if the name ends with something). I'm not sure about emacs syntax, but something like this should be generic enough to work:

```
\.(?!((jar$)|(ear$)))
```

i.e. find a dot (.) not followed by ending ($) "jar" or (|) "ear".

Comment: And what if the filename doesn't contain a dot? Or more than one dot? (Apart from the fact the the `-regex` option matches the entire filename, not just part of it)